# Master page doesn't display images after moving aspx page in a folder

Tags: html, asp.net, image, master-pages, src

I built a website by using `Master` Page. I have some `aspx` pages, and wanted to group them in folders.

But since i moved the `aspx` page in a folder, I could not view the the master page's image anymore. 
(Master page and the aspx page are not in the same folder)

In the master page displays the image in this statement:

```
<img src="~/Style/logo.jpg" />
```

I also tried writing like this:

```
<img src="<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Style/logo.jpg") %> />
```

It didn't work. Can you please help?

Comment: you should be come back a folder to access image , in your image tag src url , via add `'../'` before it ... !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using:

```
<img src="../Style/logo.jpg" />
```

or ( if its one more level depth)

```
<img src="../../Style/logo.jpg" />
```